# bxSlider not sliding and working

Tags: javascript, slider, bxslider, responsive-slides

My bxSlider is not working. I am not sure what I've done wrong. I've included all the required files and linked them correctly but it's still not doing anything. Here's there link http://www.blueappleeye.com/staging/
Please help

Comment: Can you be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the following in your browser console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

This leads you to the fact that you're loading your plugin before jQuery.

Comment: I see no change on that site (and the same two errors).

Comment: Please refresh again.

Comment: Well, they're closer together, but they're still backwards.

Comment: I've got them in this order:

 <!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
    <script src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Which correct order should I use?

Comment: I can plainly see that. As I said, you must load jQuery first. The plugins depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

I see the css file in your header...

```
<link href="css/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

... but your jquery and bxslider js files are all the way at the bottom of your page. Load these within the `<head>` tags of your page.

```
<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file // loaded locally onto your server -->
<script src="/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
```